# JQuery cookie has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm getting an error when I try to change the language German from the drop down.

> (Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}" has no method 'cookie').

All plugins are there in my html file.copied the same. Not able to fix the issue. Thanks for your support and help. Waiting for your quick response

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/custom-form-elements.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/jquery.cycle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/ksd7ghl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/etc/designs/mycomp/js/calculators/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: how is the cookie plugin used in the project? In your browser console try `$.cookie`

Answer (score 0):

There is no cookie method in standard jQuery.
Download [jquery.cookie.js.](https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method to perform Cookie related options in simple:

```
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
```

You will have to use:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Then by simply:

```
$.cookie("visits", 10);
```

This code tracks the number of times the user has visited a website: